# What's the best way to run wire from my electrical panel to my stove in my kitchen?

Tags: wiring, basement, exterior, range

I have a house with a kitchen that only has a gas hookup for the range/stove. The house is a small raised ranch on a full basement that's been finished out over the years. I want to install an induction range and so I need a minimum 50 amp circuit and think I would need to run 6/3 cable from the panel in my finished basement to the stove location in the kitchen. Is it okay to run the wire in a conduit on the outside of the foundation wall and then into the kitchen, or does it have to run internal to the house? Running wire internally would require quite a bit of sheetrock work as the finished basement has a sheetrock ceiling, and the joists run perpendicular to much of the routing to reach the stove location in the kitchen. Another option would be to run the wire through an adjacent wall cavity into the attic space, then over to the top plate over to the top plate of the wall the stove backs up to and down to a new outlet box for the stove.

Comment: Outside the wire needs to be wet rated.  Inside it will depend on the house build and which way the joist run between the panel and kitchen, if a lot of sheetrock work or a couple of small holes needed.

Comment: What's your definition of "best"? If it's "minimize drywall work", then running it in external conduit seems ideal. If it's "lowest cost", then something else might be better. If you have a different definition of "best", well then, who knows? "What's best" questions tend to get [closed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) as opinion-based since "best" simply invites opinions and we don't do those here. If you simply want to know if it's OK to run wire in external conduit, then the answer is an unqualified "YES". Please [edit] your clarification into your question.

Comment: The "best" way is to follow the local codes.

Comment: "Best" is the safest routing for the cable, following local codes of course. Secondary to that is ease of installation for the circuit. Since it's a retrofit then Occam's Razor would apply if there's more than one safe way to route the cable. I understand that you don't know much about the layout of my house, which is a small raised ranch on a full basement that's been finished out over the years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do **NOT** talk about "6/3" and "wire" in the same sentence. They are two very different things. Even limiting just to copper (aluminum is available but can complicate things):

- 6/3 *cable* is good for up to 55A
- 3 x 6 AWG *wires* is good for up to 65A
- Cable (most common types) can only be used indoors in dry locations and can be used in conduit but generally shouldn't be due to conduit fill issues.
- Wires (as long as you make sure they are wet-rated) can be used indoors or outdoors but must be in conduit *everywhere*.

##### Step 1: Current Rating

The first step should always be to figure out how much current your circuit requires. Typical for kitchen cooking appliances is anywhere from 20A to 50A. Induction ranges, because they have both an oven (sometimes 2) and very high-powered cooktop are typically rated 40A or 50A. Note that you need to always look for what the manufacturer says to install. You can't take the W ratings and divide by 240 because (a) there are various safety margins involved, including a derate for continuous use, that can make the required circuit size larger than you might expect and (b) adding up all the cooktop elements and oven elements can actually result in a higher number than the required circuit because the range internally manages things so that you don't actually have everything on at the same time. I just checked a couple and found a Samsung at 40A and a Bosch at 50A.

- 40A Circuit - 8/3 copper cable or 8 AWG copper wires or 8 AWG aluminum wires
- 50A Circuit - 6/3 copper cable or 8 AWG copper wires or 6 AWG aluminum wires

If you need 50A then you can switch between types - e.g., 6/3 *cable* inside, than transition to 8 AWG *wires* in conduit outside, then back to 6/3 *cable* inside. However, unless the inside runs are really long, it is probably simpler to stick with conduit + 8 AWG wires for the entire run. What you should *not* do is switch between copper and aluminum. Aluminum is always good at the breaker. It may or may not be good at the appliance - you need to check the specifications. If the specifications allow aluminum then you *also* need to check local rules to make sure that aluminum is allowed for branch circuits (NEC allows it, but some jurisdictions prohibit it).

##### Step 2: Installation

There are a few key things to consider:

- Conduit Type - If you are running wires outside then they must be in conduit. There are a number of different types available, but for exposed use below a certain height you have to provide *physical protection*. For example, you can use PVC schedule 80 but not PVC schedule 40. (And for PVC, remember it must be properly rated *conduit* and not *plumbing pipe*.)
- Connection - I highly recommend hardwiring any high power device, certainly a 40A or 50A range. Check the specifications and installation manual. Some appliances are designed for plug-in only, some for hardwired only, some for both. A hardwired connection removes one key point of failure, and *may* have other benefits.
- GFCI - In the past, GFCI was required for 15A/20A 120V receptacles in the kitchen. It has been expanded recently to include 240V circuits and some hardwired devices. **Check what version of NEC your jurisdiction uses and local amendments.** There are actually a few possibilities:

  - GFCI required for everything
  - GFCI required for 120V but not 240V - your range is exempt
  - GFCI required for 120V and 240V but not 240V hardwired - your range is exempt *if* you hardwire it.

GFCI protection is an incredibly important safety feature. The problem is that 240V GFCI protection has to be provided in combination with a double-breaker in your panel. That may be unavailable (certain very old panel types) or relatively expensive. (My electrician told me about his problems getting a 50A CH GFCI for a customer who insisted on plug-in for future EVSE. Initial breaker would not fit and he came close to trying to "make it fit" but eventually found that newer stock - but same SKU - of the breaker was redesigned to fit properly in certain panels. But he also knew that the same circuit hardwired would *not* have required GFCI, but customer insisted on plug-in. EVSE is a special case, but depending on local rules this can apply to a range as well.)

Comment: If you want to hardwire an appliance that has a screw terminal block, what kind of power cord is used to connect the end of the house wiring to the terminal block? From what I see some induction cooktops that are to be hardwired have a power cord installed, but stoves (oven and surface burners in one appliance) usually don't have a power cord. Can you buy a power cord with crimped on fork or loop terminations and no plug on the other end or do you have to cut off a plug?

Comment: Often power cords are just hacked up to use for hardwiring. But power cords ("cordage") are not rated for permanent wiring.  The *correct* thing to do is to install using any permanent wiring methods - i.e., cable or conduit. Since standard NM cable (Romex) isn't supposed to be used loose (the flexible few feet between appliance and junction box) and obviously you can't use rigid conduit (PVC 40 or 80, EMT, etc.) so you use flexible metal conduit - armored cable, "wire whip", etc. These are extremely common for outdoor HVAC equipment, so the larger ones I found easily (Home Depot, Lowes) are

Comment: don't have neutral (most ranges need neutral). But they're out there, or you can build your own with appropriate flexible conduit.

Comment: Can you buy 4-wire appliance cord rated for 50 A that does not have a plug on the end?

Comment: @JimStewart I am sure you can. But again, if it is to be hardwired then you **CAN'T** use cordage. It isn't rated for permanent wiring. And permanent wiring isn't rated as cordage.

Comment: Some induction cooktops for which the instructions state to hardwire **appear** to be shipped with an internally connected wiring harness that looks to me like cordage. But that may be my wrong impression from the pictures. These may be non UL approved models. Maybe the standard brands all have a proper whip. What fitting on a wall box is approved for an appliance whip or other approved method for permanent wiring.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, esp. manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact.  I edited the orig. posting to include some more information based on feedback given so far. Definitely needs to be a 50 A GFCI circuit. I have a relatively new panel with space for the breaker. I am thinking that running the cable up to and through my attic space may be best. Question is do I need to account for voltage drop on that run (about 55 feet of cable from panel to hardwired junction box behind stove)?

Comment: Voltage drop absolutely not a concern with a mostly 240V circuit under 100 feet.

Comment: Thanks for that quick response. Regarding needed amperage, for the stove I am considering (LG Model #LSIS6338F) maximum wattage if everything's running on it (not unusual for Thanksgiving/Xmas dinners) is 16343 W. By my math that would require 68 Amps. Understanding that I'd rarely (if ever) have everything running at max wattage, is 50 Amps enough for that circuit?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact...sorry, I just reread your orig. post so ignore my last...

Comment: What breaker size do the installation instructions specify?  The sticker on my GE states 13.0 kW at 240 V. This would draw 55 A, but the instructions state use "at least" a 40 A breaker. There was a 50 A breaker in place when we installed this range 30 years ago and I left it in place. 50 A may have been needed for the original builder's integrated appliance of four surface burners, a large and a small oven, and an exhaust fan. My new exhaust fan is powered by a separate 120 V circuit.

Comment: Looking at the electrical requirements, up to 50 A is recommended. Just to be sure, that's what I'd put as the range depending on model of induction stovetop/range is from 30 A to 50 A. I like overage when installing new stuff, so I'd put in a 50 Amp service just to be sure. Also allows for future upgrades that may require more amps.